# Why can a short only hold 65,536 possible values?

Tags: performance, integer, storage, memory-efficient

I understand that with a short you can have 65,536 possible ints, but why can't you have 255,256 possible values (0 to 255,255 unsigned)? I see that you could do it like this:

[image: 2 byte integer]

Has someone already thought of this? Why isn't it used?

Comment: Each byte can have 256 different values - total number of different values for 2 bytes = `256*256` = `65536`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That wouldn't work.
How would you store `254,300`?

Answer (score 1):

Because it is two bytes and 256 * 256 = 65536.

Answer (score 1):

There are 256 options for the first byte, and 256 for the second. Altogether: 256 times 256, or 65,536.

If you suggest you could write any *decimal* in the range 0 to 255,255 this way, remember you cannot write numbers such as 123,456 because 456 is not in the range 0 to 255.

(If you did the whole thing in binary, then it would work. And you'd get the correct answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to represent the numbers 500, 1,783, or 63,443 in your scheme, among many, many others. There would still be 65,536 = 2^16 unique bit patterns, hence numbers, you could represent in your scheme... So it would clearly introduce gaps, and three of the gaps it would introduce contain the three numbers mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not in the basis of 1000! 256 * 256 =  65,536